# Constrain the number of in-/outgoing edges from/to vertex?

Tags: orientdb

Currently I have a `class A extends V` and a `class B extends E`.
Now I would like to constrain the number of `B` edges that go out of `A` to say 2.
Is this possible and if it is how can I accomplish this?
I could not find anything useful about this, only about `LINK` properties but I would like to use edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use hooks (equivalent to triggers in RDBMS) to control the CRUD operations on your schema: http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/Hook.html.